# Google Cloud Spanner - Unable to create table with REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to remotely create a table in a Cloud Spanner database using the REST API. The SQL I'm attempting to run is:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT64 NOT NULL) PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

My initial attempt used the executeSql endpoint, and that resulted in a less than helpful error message:

```
Syntax error: Expected \")\" or \",\" but got keyword NOT [at 1:29]\nCREATE TABLE test (id INT64 NOT NULL) PRIMARY KEY (id)\n
```

After a while I discovered the updateDdl endpoint but when I try this by supplying the above query in the statements list, I just get an empty 200 response back and no table is created.

How can I create a table on Cloud Spanner using SQL?

**Update**

It turns out I was doing everything correct, except a bug in my code meant I wasn't sending a PATCH request, I was sending a GET request! Rather than returning a 405, Spanner happily returns a 200 in this case, but does nothing :(

Comment: The SQL statement should be: `CREATE TABLE test (id INT64 NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));`

Comment: Doesn't help, still same behaviour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[updateDdl](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases/updateDdl) is the correct method call. Note, with a 200 response, it will return a long running operation since the schema change is not instantaneous:

> The returned long-running operation will have a name of the format
>   /operations/ and can be used to track
>   execution of the schema change(s). The metadata field type is
>   UpdateDatabaseDdlMetadata. The operation has no response.

It looks like the REST API excludes the semicolon at the end:

```
PATCH https://spanner.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/instances/YOUR_INSTANCE/databases/YOUR_DATABASE/ddl

{
  "statements": [
    "CREATE TABLE Tests (TestId INT64 NOT NULL,) PRIMARY KEY(TestId)"
  ]
}
```

You can also create schemas via a UI in the [Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/spanner).

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
CREATE TABLE Tests (
    TestId INT64 NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(TestId);
```

Comment: Same behaviour, doesn't seem to do anything :(